# Remove Text from multiple folder names in fish or bash

Tags: bash, scripts, find, sh, fish

have a folder with sub folders.  I want to remove [ garbage.com ] from each folder name. I would like to remove the space after the ]

Currently

```
$ ls 
 
[ garbage.com ] happy  
[ garbage.com ] Sad   
[ garbage.com ] confused  
dog  
cat  
rat  
.....
```

After script

```
$ ls  

happy  
Sad  
confused  
dog  
cat  
rat
```

I tried the find command but the [] and space are messing me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
rename "s/\[\ garbage\.com\ \]\ //" -n *
```

The -n option will only print the planned changes. Remove the -n to actually rename the directories. Note that this will rename not only directories but also files.

To rename only directories, use the following:

```
find . -type d -exec rename -n "s/\[\ garbage\.com\ \]\ //" {} ";"
```

Comment: TY for your help.  I keep getting error "rename: not enough arguments"  Its late I will mess with it to figure it out.